random collision model
I would be grateful if somebody could help me find my answer.
I had a question about the random collision model. I don't know how I can do random collisions in the general collision model. I only have to choose a random time. I know how is the code of random collision but I don't know how to apply differences between regular and random interaction.
Thank you,
Saleh

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
